# Help with $\int \cos^6{(x)} \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Problem:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \cos^6{(x)} dx \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \cos^4{(x)} \,\, dx &=& \int { \cos^2{(x)}(\cos^2{(x)})  } \,\, dx \\
\int \cos^4{(x)} \,\, dx &=& \int { \frac{(1+\cos(2x))^2}{4}  } \,\, dx \\
\int \cos^4{(x)} \,\, dx &=&
    \int { \frac{\cos^2(2x)^2 + 2\cos(2x)+1}{4}  } \,\, dx \\
\int \cos^4{(x)} \,\, dx &=&
    \int { \frac{(\frac{1+\cos(4x)}{2} + 2\cos(2x)+1}{4}  } \,\, dx \\
\int \cos^4{(x)} \,\, dx &=&
    \int { \frac{1+\cos(4x) + 4\cos(2x)+2}{8}  } \,\, dx \\
\int \cos^4{(x)} \,\, dx &=&
    \int { \frac{\cos(4x) + 4\cos(2x)+3}{8}  } \,\, dx \\
\int \cos^4{(x)} \,\, dx &=& \frac{\sin(4x)+ 8 \sin(2x)+12x}{32} \\
\text{Let }I_6 &=& \int \cos^6{(x)} \,\, dx \\
\end{eqnarray*}
To perform this integration, I use integration by parts with
$u = \cos^5(x)$ and $dv = \cos(x) dx$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
I_6 &=& \sin(x)\cos^5(x) - \int \sin(x) 5\cos^4(x)(-\sin(x)) \,\, dx \\
I_6 &=& \sin(x)\cos^5(x) + \int 5\cos^4(x)(\sin(x))^2 \,\, dx \\
I_6 &=& \sin(x)\cos^5(x) + \int 5\cos^4(x)(1 - \cos(x))^2 \,\, dx \\
I_6 &=& \sin(x)\cos^5(x) + \int 5\cos^4(x) \,\, dx  - 5I_6 \\
6I_6 &=& \sin(x)\cos^5(x) + \int 5\cos^4(x) \,\, dx \\
6I_6 &=& \sin(x)\cos^5(x) + \frac{5\sin(4x)+ 40 \sin(2x)+60x}{32}  + C_1 \\
6I_6 &=& \frac{32\sin(x)\cos^5(x) + 5\sin(4x)+ 40 \sin(2x)+60x}{32} + C_1 \\
I_6 &=& \frac{32\sin(x)\cos^5(x) + 5\sin(4x)+ 40 \sin(2x)+60x}{192} + C  \\
\end{eqnarray*}
I believe that the above result is wrong. Using an online integral
calculator, I get:
\begin{eqnarray*}
I_6 &=& \frac{\sin(6x) + 9\sin(4x) + 45 \sin(2x) + 60x}{192} + C \\
\end{eqnarray*}
I am hoping that somebody can tell me where I went wrong.

Bob

Comment: I haven't read through your work---it may be wrong---but sometimes what happens is two different solutions are either the same, and there's just some simplification to be done, or they differ by a constant. I would suggest you take your solution and the solution from the calculator and subtract them (on Wolfram, maybe). If the result is constant, your solution is correct.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're missing a "$45$" in front of "$\sin(2x)$" in your online calculator result.

Comment: Going from this step $I_6 = \sin(x)\cos^5(x) + \int 5\cos^4(x)(1 - \cos(x))^2 \,\, dx $ to this 
$I_6 = \sin(x)\cos^5(x) + \int 5\cos^4(x) \,\, dx  - 5I_6 $ ?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 : That's a reasonable generic guess, but is not what is happening here.  The coefficients of $x$ are strong evidence of this.  Also, the difference is not a constant.

Comment: Eric Towers is right. I will update the post. Thanks Eric.

Comment: $1-\cos^2(x) \neq (1-\cos x)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use lots of trig identities and repeatedly apply integration by parts, we could've more quickly undone the entire problem by using [Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html), reducing it down to some basic integral.  This method took me about 5 steps to do (minus simplifying):

$$\int32\cos^6(x)dx=\int\cos(6x)+6\cos(4x)+15\cos(2x)-10dx$$

Since,

$\phantom{10}\cos(6x)=32\cos^6(x)-48\cos^4(x)+18\cos^2(x)-1\\\phantom06\cos(4x)=\phantom{32\cos^6(x)}+48\cos^4(x)-48\cos^2(x)+6\\15\cos(2x)=\phantom{32\cos^6(x)-48\cos^4(x)}+30\cos^2(x)-15\\10\cos(0x)=\phantom{32\cos^6(x)-48\cos^4(x)+18\cos^2(x)}+10$

Indeed, the Chebyshev polynomials are the expansions of $\cos(nx)$ in powers of $\cos(x)$.  Very useful for these types of problems.  The following is the recursive formula for the Chebyshev polynomial:

$$\begin{align}T_0(x)&=1\quad&\cos(0x)&=1\\T_1(x)&=1\quad&\cos(1x)&=\cos(x)\\T_{n+1}(x)&=2xT_n(x)-T_{n-1}(x)\quad&\cos((n+1)x)&=2\cos(x)\cos(nx)-\cos((n-1)x)\end{align}$$

Which quickly allows for the calculation of $\cos(nx)$.  For this problem, we need $\cos(6x)$ and all even below.

---

Indeed, this is why most teachers stress that algebraic (or trigonometric) simplification should be taken before applying integration techniques.  Something like reduction formulas should be a last resort.

Answer (score 3):

You could also employ the binomial theorem
\begin{align}
\cos^6x&=\frac1{64}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^6\\
&=\frac1{64}(e^{i6x}+6e^{i4x}+15e^{i2x}+20+15e^{-i2x}+6e^{-i4x}+e^{-i6x})
\\
&=\frac1{32}(\cos(6x)+6\cos(4x)+15\cos(2x)+10).
\end{align}
Which now is easy to integrate.

Comment: While this is a good technique (I would've probably personally used it or the method in my answer), I can't imagine the OP having any knowledge of the complex forms of trig functions.  Perhaps a link explaining it would be nice.

Comment: This should be the easiest way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

In your solution, when substituting the already known expression for $I_4$ (in the third line from the bottom), you forgot to multiply it by $5$. That's the only error there. Put it back in there, and you'll have a correct answer. Your answer would still look different from the output of that online integrator, but the two are in fact equivalent via trigonometric identities.

On a side note, this integral can also be found without integration by parts, but by using the same approach that worked for $I_4$ if you write $\cos^6(x)=(\cos^2(x))^3$.

Comment: I now get: $ I_6 = \frac{ 32 \sin(x)\cos^5(x) + 5\sin(4x)+ 40 \sin(2x)+60x}{192}   $ . I do not see how that is equivalent to the answer produced by the online calculator. Can you tell me how to show they are equivalent? Thanks. Bob.

Comment: Oh, it's not obvious or apparent by inspection at all! But if both solutions are correct -- and it looks like they are -- then they've got to be equivalent. With all those different trig identities sometimes it's often not easy to figure out or to observe that two expressions are in fact the same. To be completely honest, I didn't care to work it out when I posted the answer. I'm afraid it will be a very long and very tedious exercises on trig identities...

Comment: For starters, we could transform $32\sin(x)\cos^5(x)=16\cdot2\sin(x)\cos(x)\cdot\cos^4(x)=16\sin(2x)\cos^4(x)=16\sin(2x)\cdot(\cos^2(x))^2$, then change $\cos^2(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos(2x))$, and keep on going with the goal of converting everything to sine and cosine of $2x$ in both answers -- hopefully, in the end we'll see the same thing, up to a constant.

Comment: Using the complex representation it is all polynomial multiplication and binomial theorems in $$64i\sin x\cos^5x=(e^{i2x}-e^{-i2x})(e^{4ix}+4e^{i2x}+6+4e^{-i2x}+e^{-i4x})\\=e^{i6x}+4e^{i4x}+2e^{i2x}-2e^{-i2x}-4e^{-i4x}-e^{-i6x}=2i(\sin(6x)+4\sin(4x)+2\sin(2x))$$

Comment: In fact, precisely to avoid doing this -- trying to figure out far from obvious steps to prove a trig identity -- this is a nice alternative approach: take the derivatives. If the derivatives are the same, then the original expression had to be equal up to a constant, so it only remains to figure out the constant.

Comment: @LutzL I think the avoidance of complex numbers is something they want at this level.

Answer (score 0):

Using only two identities, $$\cos^2x = \frac 12 \left(1+\cos2x\right)$$
$$\cos A\cos B=\frac 12 \left[\cos(A-B)+\cos(A+B)\right]$$
We evaluate,
$$\int \cos^6x \, dx$$
Separate a $\cos^2x$ factor
$$\int \cos^6 dx \, = \, \int \cos^4 x \cos^2 x \, dx$$
Use $\cos^2x = \frac 12 \left(1+\cos2x\right)$ identity and expand,
$$\int \cos^4 x \cos^2 x \, dx \, = \, \int \left(\frac {1+\cos 2x}2\right)^2\left(\frac {1+\cos 2x}2\right)dx$$
$$=\, \frac 18 \int \left(1+3\cos 2x + 3\cos^2 2x+ \cos^3 2x\right)dx$$
Split into simpler integrals,
$$\frac 18 \int 1+3\cos 2x \, dx\;+\; \frac 3{8}\int \cos^2 2x\,dx \;+\; \frac 1{8} \int \cos^3 2x\, dx$$
Use $\cos^2x = \frac 12 \left(1+\cos2x\right)$ again,
$$= \, \frac 18 \int 1+3\cos 2x \, dx\;+\; \frac 3{16}\int 1+\cos 4x\,dx \;+\; \frac 1{8}\int \cos^2 2x \cos 2x \, dx$$
$$= \, \frac 18 \int 1+3\cos 2x \, dx\;+\; \frac 3{16}\int 1+\cos 4x\,dx \;+\; \frac 1{16}\int \left(1+\cos 4x\right) \cos 2x \, dx$$
$$= \, \frac 18 \int 1+3\cos 2x \, dx\;+\; \frac 3{16}\int 1+\cos 4x\,dx \;+\; \frac 1{16}\int \cos 2x dx + \frac 1{16} \int \cos 4x \cos 2x \, dx$$
Here use the $\cos A\cos B=\frac 12 \left[\cos(A-B)+\cos(A+B)\right]$ identity,
$$= \, \frac 18 \int 1+3\cos 2x \, dx\;+\; \frac 3{16}\int 1+\cos 4x\,dx \;+ \frac 1{16}\int \cos 2x dx +\; \frac 1{32}\int \cos 2x + \cos 6x \, dx$$
Solving one integral at a time,
$$\frac x8 + \frac 3{16}\sin 2x \;+\; \frac 3{16}\int 1+\cos 4x\,dx \;+ \frac 1{16}\int \cos 2x dx +\; \frac 1{32}\int \cos 2x + \cos 6x \, dx$$
$$= \, \frac x8 + \frac 3{16}\sin 2x \;+\; \frac 3{16}x + \frac 3{64} \sin 4x \;+\frac 1{16}\int \cos 2x dx  +\; \frac 1{32}\int \cos 2x + \cos 6x \, dx$$
$$= \, \frac x8 + \frac 3{16}\sin 2x \;+\; \frac 3{16}x + \frac 3{64} \sin 4x \;+\frac 1{32}\sin 2x dx  +\; \frac 1{32}\int \cos 2x + \cos 6x \, dx$$
$$= \, \frac x8 + \frac 3{16}\sin 2x \;+\; \frac 3{16}x + \frac 3{64} \sin 4x \;+\frac 1{32}\sin 2x \, +\; \frac 1{64} \sin 2x + \frac 1{192} \sin 6x$$
Finally simplify and add the constant $C$,
$$= \, \frac 5{16}x + \frac {15}{64}\sin 2x + \frac 3{64} \sin 4x + \frac 1{192} \sin 6x + C$$